# What was the default font in Android Studio Editor for versions < 3.6?

Tags: android, android-studio

Does anyone know how to get the text in Android-Studio 3.6 editor to look similar to the one from the previous versions? What was the default Editor font in previous versions? I've updated mine to 3.6 yesterday and it's really difficult for me to switch to the new fonts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I've ended up is `Courier New, size 12`

Comment: I don't think this was the default font for 3.5

Comment: I just updated it and I hate the new font as well not to mention the color scheme...

Comment: Consolas size 13 is the default for me with 1.2 line spacing

Comment: @breakline - Hey! Today I've updated Android Studio to Arctix Fox version and it changed the editor's font. I've set Consolas 13 as you have written. I think that was the previous font, but wasn't it 14?

Answer (score 7):

For future reference, for me it was this

`Settings -> Editor -> Font`

Change font to
`Consolas`

which was standard in IntelliJ before the update.

Answer (score 2):

Previous font was "Menlo 12"

Comment: try be more clear with your answer

Answer (score 0):

Either manually edit your font by going here:

```
Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > Font
```

or apply the theme you had before by going here:

```
Android Studio > Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance
```

For future reference, when you update AS it prompts you with a dialog that asks you whether you want to import the settings from the previous version or update to the new defaults. If you select the former then the updated version should respect your previous theme/fonts.

Comment: Yes I know where to change it, but I get the feeling the font is different in the editor and I cannot find on web what was the default one prior to 3.6

Comment: @Rixment were you using the default fonts before? What theme were you using?

Comment: Yes everything was default. Is it possible to get back to it?

Comment: And yes to your reference, I was importing from my previous configuration of AS 3.5

Comment: @Rixment I couldn't help you, sorry. I'm using a custom theme on mine and when I upgraded I kept my previous configuration so nothing changed for me. Hopefully, someone with an older AS can check their settings and see what the default font used to be and whether it changed at all.

Comment: @Rixment A colleague of mine who's still on 3.5.3 and using the defaults in darcula theme, has the font as Menlo size 12

Comment: There's no Menlo font in my distribution, just checked

Comment: @Rixment maybe it's an OS thing as well then. (We're both using Menlo on MacOs)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the original really was but I chose Droid Sans Mono, size 11.

Answer (score 0):

I've reset my editor to Menlo and the general font to Apple System font on mac. Looks similar to what it was before.